# Can the captcha load first, then the robot picture?

Tags: feature-request, captcha

This question is specifically for low bandwidth users on a recent trip to a place where I had lower internet speed. I had to wait for a significantly long period of time until the robot image loaded and then the captcha.

Is it possible for the captcha to come first and then the image loads so that you can fill in the captcha details while the image loads. It would probably save some time on the user end.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source of the captcha div, suggest the modifications to be made:

```
<div id="mainbar" class="mainbar-captcha">    
    <div style="margin-left: 0px; font-size: 150%" class="content-inside">
        <a href="http://www.jinx.com/men/shirts/video_games" target="_blank">
            <img src="/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/captcha-humans-are-dead.jpg" width="600" height="444" alt="Humans Are Dead T-Shirt" style="margin-bottom:10px;"/>
        </a>
        <form method="post" action="/captcha?s=33764f15-3135-472f-a177-063cc1f6b432">                
            <div><script type="text/javascript">
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
            theme : 'clean',
            tabindex : 0
        };
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc">
</script><noscript>
        <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0">
        </iframe><br>
        </br><textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><input name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" type="hidden" />
</noscript></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() { $("#recaptcha_response_field").focus(); });
            </script>
            <noscript>
                You must enter the confirmation code in the box above after solving the challenge
            </noscript>
            <p>
            </p>
            <input id="btn-captcha" style="font-weight: bold;" type="submit" name="post" value="&nbsp;I'm a Human Being&nbsp;" /><br>
        </form>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know javascript, so i'm in no position to suggest changes. This would have to be done by someone who has some understanding in the subject.